# LoaderManager doesn't triggered from subclass

Tags: java, android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have My MainActivity which simply implement `LoaderManager` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

And inside the overridden methods I create a `new` adapter for `RecycleView` e.g:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return NYTLoader.newNYTInstance(this);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    NYTAdapter adapter = new NYTAdapter(cursor, this);
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    int columnCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.list_column_count);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager sglm =
            new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(columnCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(sglm);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
}
```

Now inside My `NYTAdapter` I **again** implemented `LoaderManager` :

```
public class NYTAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NYTAdapter.ViewHolder> implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

To create another another adapter:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLoader: ");
    return WeatherLoader.newAllWeatherInstance(context);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    this.cursor = cursor;

    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadFinished: ");
    WeatherAdapter adapter = new WeatherAdapter(cursor, context);
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    int columnCount = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.list_column_count);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager sglm =
            new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(columnCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(sglm);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
}
```

But the problem that, The overridden methods inside `NYTAdapter` didn't triggered, I don't know why?

Comment: You do call `loaderManager.initLoader` somewhere, right?

Comment: @kalabalik I didn't call it inside the adapter, how i can call it?

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) out.

Comment: @kalabalik the adapter class doesn't have the `getLoaderManager`

Comment: Call it on the `Context` instance you pass to it in the constructor.

Comment: @kalabalik I tried that `context#` but not resolved..

Comment: Sorry, cast `context` to `YourActivity youractivity = (YourActivity) context;` and then call `youractivity.getLoaderManager`.

Comment: @kalabalik same, i extended mainactivity and it's work now, the `createLoader` invoked as well but `onLoadFinish` doesn't, you have any idea?

Comment: @kalabalik sorry, your solution worked, put it as answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is call `getLoaderManager.initLoader` on your activity or your fragment.

Comment: Ups, I think there is one more issue `YourActivity youractivity = (YourActivity) context;` and override methods inside my class cause issue, I don't know why.

Comment: What kind of issues? And please post the constructor of your adapter.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery` and it's referring to the previous data

Comment: I don't think this error message has anything to do with the code you posted above.

Comment: I think because i have `onLoadFinish` inside mainActivity and `onCreateLoader` inside my adapter, it's like trying to reopen cursor closed by the `onLoadFinish` inside mainActivity